# Renaming directories based on a pattern in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, rename, file-rename

I have a Bash script that works well for just renaming **directories** that match a criteria.

```
for name in *\[*\]\ -\ *; do
  if [[ -d "$name" ]] && [[ ! -e "${name#* - }" ]]; then
    mv "$name" "${name#* - }"
  fi
done
```

Currently if the directory looks like:

```
user1 [files.sentfrom.com] - Directory-Subject
```

It renames the directory and only the directory to look like

```
Directory-Subject (this could have different type of text)
```

How can I change the script / search criteria to now search for

```
www.ibm.com - Directory-Subject
```

and rename the directory and only the directory to

```
Directory-Subject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your code this way so that it covers both the cases:

```
for dir in *\ -\ *; do
  [[ -d "$dir" ]] || continue   # skip if not a directory
  sub="${dir#* - }"
  if [[ ! -e "$sub" ]]; then
    mv "$dir" "$sub"
  fi
done
```

Before running the script:

```
$ ls -1d */
user1 [files.sentfrom.com] - Directory-Subject/
www.ibm.com - Directory-Subject
```

After:

```
$ ls -1d */
Directory-Subject/
www.ibm.com - Directory-Subject/   # didn't move because directory existed already
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be to change `*\[*\]\ -\ *` to  `*\ -\ *`

```
for name in *\ -\ *; do
  if [[ -d "$name" ]] && [[ ! -e "${name#* - }" ]]; then
    mv "$name" "${name#* - }"
  fi
done
```

For more information, please read [glob](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) and [wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)